# What is CONF state in ESP32?

Tags: esp32, spi

When reading the technical reference for ESP32 CPUs e.g. [esp32-s2_technical_reference_manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s2_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf) you often find "CONF state", especially for SPI: "Can be configured in CONF state. ".

What does this exactly mean?